# Fabric.js specify lineCap style

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In `html5 canvas` it is possible to specify [`lineCap` style](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_linecap.asp) for the line ends.

E.g.:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineCap="round";    // <-- here lineCap is specified
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(200,20);
```

Possible options are: `butt (Default), round, square`.

My question is:
How to specify `lineCap` style when creating the `Line` with [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/)?

```
var line = new fabric.Line(
    [0, 100, 200, 100],
    {
        strokeWidth: 5
        // I presume some option should be specified here, but how is it should be called?
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer

Posting it here, as it is not obvious from the fabric.js documentation:

```
var line = new fabric.Line(
    [0, 100, 200, 100],
    {
        strokeWidth: 5,
        strokeLineCap: "round"   // <-- this makes 'round' line ends style
    }
);
```